# Could “noyal” replace “nucléaire”?

Tags: adjectifs, linguistique

The French language is quite logic and has a fairly efficient morphological system. For example, it can create nouns meaning 'the place where something takes place' using the forms *-erie* and *-oir*, and it often keeps the same 'root' in the nominal and adjectival form (*fer*/*ferré*).

Similarly, the adjectives *royal* and *loyal* have been derived from *roi* and *loi* respectively. It seems like French likes this form. But the noun *noyau* reverts back to the Latin root in the adjective *nucléaire* instead of *noyal -e -aux*. This seems odd, particularly as the masculine plural form would be identical to the plural of the noun.

And yet, compared to English, French has quite a tendency to chose French roots over Greek/Latin. Note the pairs *éteindre/extinguish*, *presqu'île/peninsula* or *foyer/focus*. I'm not saying *noyal* exists now, I'm asking if it conforms to the aesthetics and logic of the French language.

Comment: What you are asking is not clear at all, can you clarify your question? What's this "gap" you are talking about ?

Comment: In deed, I´ve seen _noyal_ replace _nucleaire_ in scientific publications (One I´m sure of, in an acronym, and the other one was on the Internet but I cant find it, I remember I was looking to translate something about nebula stars). I had never seen it before though I studied physics and electronics extensively (but not in France). Maybe the publications came from Quebec, I dont remember.

However the French language always (since the 16th cent.) privileged neologisms based on etymology, like aqua -> eau -> aqueux (a word from the 16th cent.). So nucleus -> noyau -> nucléaire.

Comment: I´ll add that this pattern of privileging the Greek/Latin radical has been used extensively in medicine and chemy (some would say it was created for it) with the establishment of the College de France, and the Edit de Villers-Cotterêts forcing the use of French and the invention of new words.

Comment: One of the problems with considering the French language (particularly in relation to neologisms) is that everyone studies it through the lens of English, only comparing these two languages. In Arabic the same three-lettered root is used throughout (for example ṣ/w/r for picture, photography, photographer, imagination).

Comment: I added a line in my answer to say that an adjective *noyal* from the noun "noyau" would not conform to the logic of the French language. That's what I'd been trying to explain...

Comment: What do you mean by "French has quite a tendency to chose French roots" what do you call French roots? The vast majority of French vocabulary comes from Latin and Greek. Plus a little Celt and a little German and the rest is insignificant.  I do not understand either your comparison between French and English, nearly 60% of the words in English are of Latin or Greek origin, nearly half of which having been brought into English when the Normans invaded Britain.

Comment: *extinguish*, *peninsula*, *foyer* and *focus* are all words of Latin origin brought into English via the French language.

Comment: @hautfrançais When you say "everyone studies it through the lens of English" I think you are entirely mistaken. It's a point of view that no linguist would support.

Answer (score 10):

You seem to have the wrong assumptions.

"Royal" and "loyal" are adjectives derived from nouns. "Noyau" is a noun derived from a word that was an adjective in Latin. And no parallelism can be drawn in the origin and history of those words.
An adjective *noyal* from the noun "noyau" would not conform to the logic of the French language.

"Royal" derives from latin *regalis* and loyal from latin *legalis*. The derivation from *rex* and *lex* was done in latin before the words existed in French, so no law can be inferred about all French nouns ending in "oi" having adjectives derived from them ending in "al".

"Noyau" is a noun that happens to end with *au* in the singular. This "au" ending of the noun has nothing to do with the rule that says that in French most adjectives (but not all, lots of exceptions) ending with "al" in the singular will end with "aux" in the plural.
 There's no such noun as <del>noya</del>l, and there's never been. The only occurrence of "Noyal" in French is for some place names in Brittany<sup>*</sup>. 
And this « noyal » is said to come from Latin *novale* or *novalium* designating some recently cleared piece of land.

The noun "noyau" comes from Late Latin adjective *nucalis* itself derived from latin *nux* (→"noix"). *Nucalis* meant "having the size of a nut". The adjective *nucalis* and its diminutive *nucleus* gave old French *noiel*→*noiaux* that gave the noun *noyau* (1530) to designate the stone of a fruit.

It started being used in a figurative sense in the 16th century.

Two adjectives are derived from "noyau". "Nucléaire" and "nucléal", they're roughly synonyms (but a scientist might explain a difference in use), nucléaire being by far and large the most used.

<sup>* Which could lead us to think the name could be of Celtic origin.</sup>

Comment: Amazing answer, says everything and thoroughly explained. +1

Comment: +1 (would it be only for mentioning *nucléal*)

Answer (score 1):

Pour [*noyale*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/noyale) le TLF donne : "Toile de chanvre écrue très résistante, utilisée autrefois pour la confection des voiles des navires. Noyales à quatre, à six fils (Ac. 1835, 1878)."… et le correcteur d'orthographe ne le connait pas. Conclusion : l'oreille francophone du XXI<sup>e</sup> siècle ignore ce mot.

Les multiples influences subies par les mots ne permettent pas de dériver une loi de quelques exemples.

*Laure* vous donne une explication grammaticale, mais intuitivement un *noyau* n'a pas de comportement humain, donc, bien que vivant il ne peut être *noyal*, d'autant plus qu'il est caché ; la notion de noyau s'est d'abord rattachée au fruit.

C'est la science qui a apporté le terme *nucléaire*, qui, sauf erreur de ma part, n'est pas employé dans l'arboriculture.

Pour l'homme on emploie parfois le mot *cœur* pour renvoyer au *noyau* de son être, mais *noyau* et *nucléaire* ne renvoient pas aux mêmes imaginaires.

Comment: "Noyale is a noun", and there's no such adjective as noyal (without an "e" in the end). The name of this type of cloth comes from one of the towns of Noyal and has nothing to do with the"noyau".

Comment: @Laure Bien sûr - C'est seulement un essai pour indiquer que la sonorité *noyal* ne peut rien invoquer comme entité en français ; j'essaye d'utiliser l'approche intuitive pour indiquer que les règles ne sont pas réversibles et qu'il est risqué de construire des raisonnements en essayant de rapprocher les résultats de ces dernières. L'évolution du mot *noyau* est le résultat de l'évolution de la langue parlée qui fait référence à un objet perceptible à l’œil nu , celui de *nucléaire* un choix scientifique, savant et précis qui recouvre un concept qui nécessite des instrument pour être perçu.

Comment: Et pourtant 'noyau' s'utilise dans le domaine de l'atomique.

Comment: @hautfrançais bien sûr. Noyau est un terme scientifique, utilisé pour la première fois avec un sens scientifique en biologie (19e siècle), puis en météorologie, en géologie, en physique, etc. C'est toujours la "partie centrale" de quelque chose, comme le noyau au milieu du fruit.

Comment: "*Noyale*" a ici plus de liens avec le mot "*noeud*" (les noeuds des mailles du tissu) qu'avec le mot "*noyau*".

Comment: @air-dex absolument pas, Une noyale c'est un toile de la ville de Noyal-sur-Vilaine et sa région.

Comment: @hautfrançais Le domaine atomique a repris le mot *noyau* et a dérivé ensuite *nucléaire* du latin n'ayant pas de *noyal* sous la main.